# Is it possible to change the visibility of a private repo using the GitHub API?

Tags: github, github-api

I've been looking for a way to convert my private repositories to public ones, but since there are so many of them, I preferred to do it the easy way and resorted to the GitHub API, but this one, as far as I could find, only allows editing the visibility of repositories that are public. Looking through the most up-to-date documentation, I realized that the only endpoints available for access while authenticated are ([Repositories](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/repos#list-public-repositories), [Endpoints available](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/overview/endpoints-available-for-github-apps)):

- `GET /user/repos`
- `POST /user/repos`
- `POST /user/projects`

I also tried using the browser console and generating a log when I make a request to change visibility, but it doesn't seem to make any requests to the GitHub API.

Answer (score 7):

You can sets a repo's visibility to public (or private) with this [REST endpoint](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#update-a-repository):

```
PATCH /repos/{owner}/{repo}
```

This *does* work for repos that are private (despite [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64732670/is-it-possible-to-change-the-visibility-of-a-private-repo-using-the-github-api/68051166#comment114496056_64740260)). And if the repo already has the visibility being requested, the API will return an error message indicating that status.

### `visibility` Parameter

> Can be `public` or `private`. If your organization is associated with an enterprise account using GitHub Enterprise Cloud or GitHub Enterprise Server 2.20+, `visibility` can also be `internal`. The `visibility` parameter overrides the `private` parameter when you use both along with the `nebula-preview` preview header.

### Examples

#### [`curl`](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html)

```sh
curl \
  -X PATCH \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.nebula-preview+json" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/hello-world \
  -d '{"visibility":"public"}'
```

#### [`gh`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_api)

```sh
gh api -X PATCH /repos/octocat/hello-world -fvisibility=public --preview nebula
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, at this time I have solved my issue. I'll do a quick test in a moment to confirm, but this seems legit as you reference directly the github api docs, so this will be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

2022: I would use the [GitHub CLI](https://github.com/cli/cli/releases) and its [`gh repo edit` command](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_edit):

```
cd /path/to/local/repo
gh repo edit --visibility=public
```

---

2020: Yes, you can, but as mention in the [repository API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#update-a-repository), this is still in beta:

> You can set the visibility of a repository using the new `visibility` parameter in the Repositories API, and get a repository's visibility with a new response key.
> For more information, see the [blog post](https://developer.github.com/changes/2019-12-03-internal-visibility-changes/).
>
> To access repository visibility during the preview period, you must provide a custom media type in the Accept header:
>
> application/vnd.github.nebula-preview+json

Comment: Yes, I already knew that, but what I'm looking for is to edit the visibility of a repository that is already private, the endpoints you mention are for public repositories. To access private repositories and then edit them (if possible) you need to access the API with a token and different endpoints, which are the ones I put above, do you know any other way?

Comment: @Alois I do not. I thought those endpoints were enough.